# Git pushing ignored files

Tags: git, gitignore

I set up an online project in the yii2 framework on my local and started maintaining the code using Git. A few days later I decided to ignore a few files & folders like "vendor, runtime and upload" folders. I have 3-5 git branches now. I also created a repository in Github website for saving my changes online. But, all the ignored files & directory are getting pushed to GitHub. The total directory size (excluding `.git` directory) is around 632MB. The '.git' directory itself is 1.3 GB.

I don't want to push the ignored files and directories.

I used the following command to remove already added files & folders from Git.

```
git rm --cached <file> 
git commit -m "to save the changes"
```

But when I push the files to the server, it still pushes stagged and ignored files & directories.

I want to permanently ignore the files & directories I added in the '.gitignore' file from all my Git branches and also want to push rest of the files in Git. Here is the copy of my Git ignore file. Every time I use 
the following command, it adds the ignored files as well.

```
git add --all *
```

The Git ignore file:

```
# windows thumbnail cache
Thumbs.db

# composer itself is not needed
composer.phar

# composer vendor dir
/protected/vendor

# runtime dir
/protected/frontend/runtime/
/protected/backend/runtime/

#tempfiles
*~
/assets/**
/uploads/*
*.log
```

@Drubio Here's the directory structure:

```
/assests
/uploads
/protected
    /backend
       /runtime
       /<rest all the directory by default installed with yii2
    /common
    /frontend
       /runtime
       /<rest all the directory by default installed with yii2
    /vendor
    /console
    /environment

/.git
<few files here on root>
.gitignore
.htaccess
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Is your .gtiignore in the top level of your project directory?

Comment: The directory tree would be helpful to see if we can help you.

Comment: When you say that you're pushing them, are they in your tree in the current commit?  Or are you pushing historical versions of them?  ie, do you _see_ them on GitHub?  Or are you noticing that it's pushing 1.4 GB and that's the problem?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal yes my ".gitignore" file it in the top level of my project directory.

Comment: @Drubio Now sure how the directory structure is going to help but, I will add it anyways.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I was trying to push the history version earlier i.e. my master branch. It never worked, but now I am trying to push my current branch. My current branch have files about 475MB (including the vendors and runtime folder)  and including uploads its 632MB and my '.git' directory size is 1.3 GB. I am noticing the size being pushed in the Git. I am not yet succeeded to push any of the branches on the GitHub server.

Comment: @Drubio I have added the directory structure in my question description.

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is that your ignored files were already pushed to the remote branhc
try the following set of commands:

## to see the unwanted files:

`git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard`

## remove the unwanted files

`git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached`

## commit the changes

`git commit -am "Removed unwanted files"`

## push the changes:

`git push origin <branchname>`

Comment: Isn't the `git ls` commands for git large files repository? None of my file sizes more than 5MB.

Comment: the `git ls-files` command is similar to `ls` on your terminal, used to show information about files in the index and the working tree

check here for details: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dalton. My branch is not yet added to Git, I am currently maintaining the code and branches on my local and not able to push the branch on the Git.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the unwanted files using `git rm` will remove those files from the file-tree in the commit where you removed them, but it will not make the Git repo smaller, since Git keeps a history of all the old commits still in the repository, and therefore of all the files they contain.

I don't want to go into how to rewrite the history to remove those large files - that's discussed at length here: [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository) but if you just started using Git for this project, it might be easiest to start with a fresh repo.